Download a file from SharePoint using C# even though that files is still open in SharePoint
public void DownloadFilesFromSharePoint(string UserName, string Pwd, string spsiteurl, string filePathSharePoint, string filePathLocal)
    {
        //Load Libraries from SharePoint
        ClientContext ctxSite = GetSPOContext(UserName, Pwd, spsiteurl);
        ctxSite.Load(ctxSite.Web.Lists);
        ctxSite.ExecuteQuery();

        // Lấy tệp từ SharePoint
        FileInformation fileInformation = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctxSite, filePathSharePoint);

        // Lưu tệp vào ổ đĩa
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePathLocal))
        {
            fileInformation.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }

    }

I have a code like this. How can I download a file from SharePoint using C# even though that file is still opened in SharePoint?
Because when I try to download it. It requires me to close the file before downloading.
Thanks!

You are facing this issue because of  locking mechanism in SharePoint. SharePoint puts a lock on the file to prevent concurrent modifications which can lead to data corruption or inconsistencies.to achieve your requirement you could check if the file is not being edited but just opened, you can programmatically check out the file before downloading and check it back in afterward. another way is you could use SharePoint REST API to download the file.
